# Is it possible to iterate through some particular number of items in the beginning of a generic List on a MVC razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I think the title speaks for itself,
I know I can use `for` loop but ideally I'm looking for something like

```
List<MyClass> myList = ...
foreach (MyClass item in myList.Take(3)) {
    //...
}
```

Can I do something similar?

Thanks

UPDATE

I tried this code on a razor MVC view and it didn't work, I got the `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass>' does not contain a definition for 'Take'` exception. I was confused by that so asked this question. Obviously the question was not correct so I updated it.

I tried adding `@using System.Linq` on top of the view but it still doesn't work, I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: yes with LINQ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx

Comment: What you have already works. Did you even try it? (`System.Linq` from *System.Core.dll*)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is with the code sample you've posted. Why can't you use exactly that?

Comment: Sorry guys, It does work in codebehind but when I try to do it on a ASP.NET MVC view using razor I get an exception `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass>' does not contain a definition for 'Take'` that confused me, what do I need to do?

Comment: In this case you have to include the namespace inside the page. put "@using System.Linq" on top of the page.

Comment: Thanks Lucas S , I tried that but still getting the same exception

Comment: And a reference to System.Core? The `Take` extension method is defined in System.Core.dll, so if you don't have it referenced then while you've the namespace correct for it to be used, it isn't there for it to be found.

Comment: @JonHanna - Burja stated in a previous comment `It does work in codebehind but when I try to do it on a ASP.NET MVC view using razor I get an exception`. So I'm pretty sure all of his references are right.

Comment: @Burjua - Did you ever find your solution?

Comment: @M.Babcock, no I have the reference to System.Core and it works in a controller but doesn't in the view. I'm new to MVC so I stuck and gave up, used `for` loop instead. If someone finds a solution and share it, it would be great.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The code you've given is the code that works. Why didn't you just try it?

If you did try it, and it didn't work, please show your exact code, and the error you got. (Did you perhaps forget to include the System.Linq namespace, or a reference to System.Core?)

Answer (score 1):

```
            int[] grades = { 59, 82, 70, 56, 92, 98, 85 };

            IEnumerable<int> topThreeGrades =
                grades.OrderByDescending(grade => grade)**.Take(3)**;

            Console.WriteLine("The top three grades are:");
            foreach (int grade in topThreeGrades)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(grade);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
myList.Take(3).ToList().ForEach( ... );
```

Or using PLinq (.NET 4 only):

```
myList.Take(3).AsParallel().ForAll( ... );
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment it sounds like you are missing the using statement for System.Linq and maybe even System.Collections.Generic.

```
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: `@using System.Linq` doesn't help, still getting the same exception.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think you may also need to include a using statement for `System.Collections.Generic`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a standard `for`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    var item = myList[i];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood you target.
So, try to create o own extention method to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Utility
{
    public static class IEnumerableUtility
    {
        public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
                action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The you will be able to what you want to do:

```
using Utility;

...    

myList.Take(3).ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

**UPDATE:**

Maybe, you'd be better if you create the projection in controller side. Anyway, you can call the *take* method directly, without extension method:

```
List<MyClass> myList = ...
foreach (MyClass item in System.Linq.Enumerable.Take(myList, 3)) {
    //...
}
```

try it!

Best regards,
Lucas

Comment: `List<>` already contains a `ForEach` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx. What advantage does your implementation provide?

Comment: The advantage is that it works for any list that implement IEnumerable interface.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` has an extension method for `ToList` which minimizes that benefit. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You don't need to cast your IEnumerable list to a List<> type to use lambda expression to iterate through items. You save a step! :) In fact, I prefer to use the old "for" or "foreach" statements. I was just try to give an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the code written works in .Net 3.5 and above, make sure you include the `System.Linq` namespace.

```
using System.Linq
```